# How to make small but necessary edits in an area "obscure" to many

Tags: discussion

Here is a question from the IBM Mainframe world:

[Formatting output file after an INCLUDE condition in JCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469436/formatting-output-file-after-an-include-condition-in-jcl)

And another:

[Mainframe Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995296/mainframe-dataset)

A very quick explanation for the first: All JCL (Job Control Language) statements start with a double forward-slash starting in "column 1" (all lines must begin //). JCL, despite the "L", is in not very much of a sense a "language". It is highly specific, and its job is to define what programs are going to be run and what resources they are going to use. There is no way to transfer-of-control (other than a simple "don't do the next bit depending on what has already happened) and no way to "iterate".

So, JCL does *nothing* except it's specific task. The program that is being executed in a particular "step" of the JCL is doing the work, and for "utility" programs there are "Control Cards", and it is Sort Control Cards that are shown in the question.

A fly-in-the-ointment which has to be considered is that around 90% (I made that figure up, but it is most people without substantial experience on the Mainframe) of people call everything that is in the "job stream" JCL.

I'll get to the actual question very soon, but first the second post.

The answer given shows Sort Control Cards. Sort Control Cards have their own particular syntax. One throwback is that column one must always be blank (each line must start with a blank).

After editing to remove the JCL tag on the first question, I twice tried to edit the post (as well as grammar things) to remove the references to JCL (because there is none shown, and there is no actual relation to the question, or any possible answer). Neither of the subsequent edits became final.

With the second question, I made the edit for the leading blanks on the Sort Control Cards (vital for correct syntax) and had to make a "trivial" edit to get up to the necessary minimum six characters for an edit.

I included details in the comment on the edit explaining the above (in somewhat shorter terms).

The difference between JCL and "Control Cards" is important. If someone gets a JCL error,they should look in the JCL manuals. If someone gets a "Control Card" error, they should look in the particular manual(s) for that utility. If someone doesn't know the difference between JCL and Control Cards, they will not know which manual they should be looking in before even asking the question here.

With the "leading blanks" on the Sort Control Card, there is an Accepted Answer with a syntax error (or the same one, twice). Someone might ask another question saying that the syntax in an answer here is incorrect.

My question(s):

- Do I just wait until I'm "grown up" enough to make my own edits "unmolested"? That will take some time, due to the "obscure" nature of the thing meaning there is not a large volume of questions.
- Do I just keep editing, hoping that it will eventually "stick"?
- Do I just ignore it?
- Do I do something else, if so, what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **leave a comment** on the answer explaining the issue and the solution.

From there, the answerer could see it and correct his post. Or a knowledgable high-rep user may edit the post to correct the issue. In any case, the comment will suffice to warn visitors of any technical inaccuracies.

Comment: OK. I'm not so sure that people coming in to "grab some code" actually read the comments, particularly if extended so have to do something to look "over the page". The knowledgeable high-rep user has already *not* edited anything, despite comments already having been made at the time relating to the point. Ditto the TS didn't take note of the comments and edit. However, maybe this is all that can be done.

Comment: If they try the posted code without reading the comments, then find it doesn't work, they will almost surely return and read over the comments to find out why. I would make the edits if it were in an area remotely familiar to me, but unfortunately I am so far removed from this subject that I would not be comfortable changing any aspect of the answer besides English.

Comment: In any case, I interpret that, on both questions, the highest-voted answer is correct and complete. That's usually the answer people will spring for, so I think there is less danger of incorrect answers being a problem.

Comment: On the first question, there was an upvote after I asked this :-). On the second question, it is the accepted answer which has the syntax error (four upvotes). Yes, the TS must have worked out that problem, and then been thoughtless-enough not to post a comment. Some, I feel, may not do the research and post another question here, or somewhere else.

Comment: Well, I don't see a comment on that one pointing out the error. Perhaps you should add one :)

Comment: Will do. I attempted the edit yesterday and didn't want to comment assuming the edit would "work". Without the comment it seems a little less "critical". With formatting in here, where four blanks denote "code", another leading blank is easily lost. Before I knew I could edit (sort of) other people's posts, I'd leave a comment and then delete it if actioned. I'll do that now, thanks.

Comment: That worked very well. The second post was updated within a few minutes.

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad you got it resolved.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Wood-for-the-trees job. I'll go back to that until I'm grown-up enough for edits.